# Why is it not necessary to await the return of a database query

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, database, async-await

I set up my server in the typical MVC structure. The function in the controller requires me to await on the promise given when the function in the model queries my database. If the query returns a promise, how come I don't need to await it?

```js
//model - why don't I have to make this an async/ await function?
const findUser = (name) => {
  const author = User.findOne({
    where: {
      firstName: name,
    },
  });
  return author;
};

//controller
const getUser = async (ctx) => {
  ctx.body = await messages.findUser(ctx.request.body);
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`User.findOne()` immediately returns a `Promise`.  That promise is immediately returned to `getUser`.  `getUser` is what does the waiting.

If you were going to do *anything* with what `User.findOne()` would resolve to within the `getUser` call, *then* you would have to `await` within `getUser`.

To be more plain, `author` is a bad variable name.  It doesn't represent an actual value.  Instead, it represents the promise of a value.  You can get promises of values quickly.  It takes time to fulfill them.

Answer (score 1):

A promise is an abstraction of a value with the semantics that either the value will eventually be available (a 'resolved' promise) or it will eventually be established that the value will not be retrieved ( a 'rejected' promise ).

The value or the error, resp., are available through the arguments of the promise's `then` method which are themselves functions whose argument is the value or the error, resp.; These function define how to process the value once it becomes available.

The encapsulating promise on the other hand becomes available immediately, thus you don't need to await it.